# Почему не отображается логотип в Firefox и Opera?

Tags: html, css, кроссбраузерность, кроссплатформенность

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не отображается логотип в Firefox и Opera?
Во всех остальных браузерах логотип виден. Что не так в коде?
Заранее благодарен.

```css
#block {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 414px;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  <img src="img\Logo.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо друг, за быстрый ответ. Причина была, как мне подсказал "void" в простом слеше:
 <img src="img/Logo.png" />, было  <img src="img \ Logo.png" />
По больше бы таких людей, которым не безразличны чужие проблемы!!!
Теперь логотип на хосте отображается и в Firefox и Opera. А раньше отображался только с локального адреса.

ОГРОМНОЕ ВСЕМ СПАСИБО!!! И отдельное СПАСИБО "void"!!!

P.S. Подскажите,пожалуйста, почему на почту пришло 3 ответа, а здесь показывает только один ответ? И как мне комментировать ответы тех, кто ответил на почту, обратных адресов там нет, есть только "noreply@sezn.ru"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежний ответ пропал, так что повторю для логического завершения:

Дело в слэше, у вас:

```
<img src="img\Logo.png" />
```

А должно быть так:

```
<img src="img/Logo.png" />
```

Так как локально на Windows первый вариант работать будет, но на "настоящем" хостинге - нет.

Comment: Вот эти слова были адресованы тебе, но не знал как ответить:

Спасибо друг, за быстрый ответ. По больше бы таких людей, которым не безразличны чужие проблемы!!! Теперь логотип на хосте отображается и в Firefox и Opera. А раньше отображался только с локального адреса.

P.S. А не подскажешь, почему я не могу наградить человека за ответ?

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста. Насчет наградить - то, если я не ошибаюсь, такая возможность появляется у участника через некоторое время после регистрации и проявления активности.

Answer (score -1):

Потому что ID в css задается чере #, то есть писать надо 
 #block  {
  width:70px;
height:70px;
margin:0; 
padding:0;
margin-top:0px; задается без px и зачем пиcать если выше уже указанно margin:0;
margin-left:414px; тогда проще напсиать margin:0 0 0 414px  и убрать все апарметры margin выше;
box-shadow:none; зачем??? 
}

Comment: Спасибо друг, за быстрый ответ. Причина была, как мне подсказал "void" в простом слеше:
 <img src="img/Logo.png" />, было  <img src="img \ Logo.png" />
По больше бы таких людей, которым не безразличны чужие проблемы!!!